# Akka streams change return type of 3rd party flow/stage

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a graph that reads from sqs, writes to another system and then deletes from sqs. In order to delete from sqs i need a receipt handle on the  SqsMessage object

In the case of Http flows the signature of the flow allows me to say which type gets emitted downstream from the flow,

```
Flow[(HttpRequest, T), (Try[HttpResponse], T), HostConnectionPool]
```

In this case i can set T to SqsMessage and i still have all the data i need.

However some connectors e.g google cloud pub sub emits a completely useless  (to me) pub sub id.

Downstream of the pub sub flow I need to be able to access the sqs message id which i had prior to the pub sub flow.

What is the best way to work around this without rewriting the pub sub connector

I conceptually want something a bit like this:

```
Flow[SqsMessage] //i have my data at this point
within(
.map(toPubSubMessage)
.via(pubSub))

... from here i have the same type i had before within however it still behaves like a linear graph with back pressure etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PassThrough integration pattern. 
As example of usage look on [akka-streams-kafka](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/akka/kafka/scaladsl/Producer.scala) -> Class `akka.kafka.scaladsl.Producer` -> Mehtod def f`low[K, V, PassThrough]`

So just implement your own Stage with `PassThrough` element, example in`akka.kafka.internal.ProducerStage[K, V, PassThrough]`

```
package my.package

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.ActorAttributes.SupervisionStrategy
import akka.stream.stage._

final case class Message[V, PassThrough](record: V, passThrough: PassThrough)

final case class Result[R, PassThrough](result: R, message: PassThrough)

class PathThroughStage[R, V, PassThrough]
  extends GraphStage[FlowShape[Message[V, PassThrough], Future[Result[R, PassThrough]]]] {

  private val in = Inlet[Message[V, PassThrough]]("messages")
  private val out = Outlet[Result[R, PassThrough]]("result")
  override val shape = FlowShape(in, out)

  override protected def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes) = {
    val logic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) with StageLogging {
      lazy val decider = inheritedAttributes.get[SupervisionStrategy]
        .map(_.decider)
        .getOrElse(Supervision.stoppingDecider)
      val awaitingConfirmation = new AtomicInteger(0)
      @volatile var inIsClosed = false

      var completionState: Option[Try[Unit]] = None

      override protected def logSource: Class[_] = classOf[PathThroughStage[R, V, PassThrough]]

      def checkForCompletion() = {
        if (isClosed(in) && awaitingConfirmation.get == 0) {
          completionState match {
            case Some(Success(_)) => completeStage()
            case Some(Failure(ex)) => failStage(ex)
            case None => failStage(new IllegalStateException("Stage completed, but there is no info about status"))
          }
        }
      }

      val checkForCompletionCB = getAsyncCallback[Unit] { _ =>
        checkForCompletion()
      }

      val failStageCb = getAsyncCallback[Throwable] { ex =>
        failStage(ex)
      }

      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull() = {
          tryPull(in)
        }
      })

      setHandler(in, new InHandler {
        override def onPush() = {
          val msg = grab(in)
          val f = Future[Result[R, PassThrough]] {
            try {
              Result(// TODO YOUR logic
                msg.record,
                msg.passThrough)
            } catch {
              case exception: Exception =>
                decider(exception) match {
                  case Supervision.Stop =>
                    failStageCb.invoke(exception)
                  case _ =>
                    Result(exception, msg.passThrough)
                }
            }

            if (awaitingConfirmation.decrementAndGet() == 0 && inIsClosed) checkForCompletionCB.invoke(())
          }
          awaitingConfirmation.incrementAndGet()
          push(out, f)
        }

        override def onUpstreamFinish() = {
          inIsClosed = true
          completionState = Some(Success(()))
          checkForCompletion()
        }

        override def onUpstreamFailure(ex: Throwable) = {
          inIsClosed = true
          completionState = Some(Failure(ex))
          checkForCompletion()
        }
      })

      override def postStop() = {
        log.debug("Stage completed")
        super.postStop()
      }
    }
    logic
  }
}
```